# How to fix "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

im getting troubles with an element from Application Suite Package.

When Im adding it in table fields and try to drag it im getting this error:
[Check Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKqk0.png)
(My model its an empty project that include ApplicationSuite)

Upd:
I have already sync the whole Database. And also I have tried to use this element(ItemId) in other model and after build I didnt get any errors at build, but the element still dont work in any of my models.

Comment: Have you tried adding a new field (string) via right-click menu and then changing the field EDT property to ItemId?

Comment: Yes , I have tried a lot of things. At the end this "ItemId" include ItemIdBase and some other elements which are from another packages

Comment: Select the project your Table2 is in, right click ItemId in the AOT, select "Add to project" and select Yes when asked something-or-the-other about copying it over models. Then try adding the ItemId from your project by drag-and-drop to Table2?

Comment: Consider making your comment an answer so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Select the project your Table2 is in (If it is not in a project, first create a project and add the table in that project.), right click ItemId in the AOT, select "Add to project" and select Yes when asked something-or-the-other about copying it over models. Then try adding the ItemId from your project by drag-and-drop to Table2?

Comment: I already find the problem. ItemId extend ItemIdBase which is in other Model and 2 more items that is included in ItemdId. I had to add 3 models Directory,Ledger and SourceDocumentationTypes.

Answer (score 0):

I already find the problem. ItemId extend ItemIdBase which is in other Model and 2 more items that is included in ItemdId. I had to add 3 models Directory,Ledger and SourceDocumentationTypes.